# How can I add maven artifact into an existing maven project

Tags: maven

How can I add  maven artifact into an existing maven project.I understand that I can build a jar locally  and use file: protocol but this is  possible using maven also.

For example I have a basic maven project

[https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_make_my_first_Maven_projec](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_make_my_first_Maven_project)t  and the artifact:

```
   <repositories>
     <repository>
       <id>myrepo.org</id>
       <name>MyRepository</name>
       <url>http://mywork.com/repository</url>
     </repository>
   </repositories>

   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.ethereum</groupId>
     <artifactId>ethereumj-core</artifactId>
     <version>1.1.0-RELEASE</version>
```

I tried adding the code above to  the project pom.xml fails because  dependency is not in central maven repo.

> mvn clean install

I then tried  editing my settings.xml by adding the  tag, that also failed  because  dependency was not found.

Im overlooking something pretty basic here.

Comment: do you mean you want to add dependency of your private jar in pom.xml

Comment: Do you have this project u want to inject (your private one) in .m2 folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven works on the concept of local and remote repositories.
The **local repository** refers to a copy on your own installation that is a cache of the remote downloads, and also contains the temporary build artifacts that you have not yet released.

**Remote repository** is repository you access the artifacts via file or http / ftp protocols , it can be an internal repo or a remote public hosted.

When you add dependency maven search that artifact in local if not found then remote repo will be searched. Still not found then error is reported.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html

In your case, 'ethereumj-core' can not be located neither of location, you need find this jar and do a manual install to local repo.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=< folder >\ethereumj-core.1.1.0-RELEASE.jar -DgroupId=org.ethereum
-DartifactId=ethereumj-core -Dversion=1.1.0-RELEASE -Dpackaging=jar
```

once properly installed maven should be able find this artifact when you add this as dependency to any of the projects (in pom.xml).

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.ethereum</groupId>
     <artifactId>ethereumj-core</artifactId>
     <version>1.1.0-RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```